# What would be some reasons why executing a binary directly would fail vs executing it via ctest would pass?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, bin, ctest

I have some tests in my project. When I run ctest, all the tests pass. This includes when I run with -R specifically limiting the executed tests to the bin in question and -V to check that the path each of them is using is the same. All other binaries run and pass successfully except 1. I can't figure out why, but some cursory investigation reveals the magical hand wave of
"ctests sets up an environment for the tests, which can affect the behavior of the tests"

These tests can be run in parallel or sequentially, but it doesn't affect the outcome, so this excludes test order being a contributing factor.

Ultimately, I want to know if I can trust the results of CTest even if executing the bin directly gives contradictory results.

Additional Information: There are 5 tests in the binary which is failing when run directly, specifically 2 of the tests inside are having asserts fail, expecting a value of 1 but the value is 0. When I attempt to debug, these tests pass.

Comment: Needs much more detail -- "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.  How does it fail, what are the errors, what have you done to debug the section that is failing?  Did you add logging or use a debugger?  Memory corruption is a typical answer, but without data who knows?

Comment: I added some additional information, but I'm not looking for someone to debug why the bin is failing, as the question states I'm looking for some reasons why executing the binary directly would fail vs ctest would pass.

Comment: "It depends".  Memory corruption can be hidden by adding test code that changes stack and heap allocations.  Timing errors, race conditions, deadlocks, output corruption, etc. can be hidden by adding test code that changes the timing.  I'm probably forgetting others, but timing and memory are the big ones.